# sudo apt update warning because of vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal

```py
meet@meet-pc:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for meet: 
Hit:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                     
Hit:2 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease             
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease           
Hit:4 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease             
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease              
Hit:6 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease          
Reading package lists... Done                                              
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_IN) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
```

[Terminal image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJtR7.png)
terminal warning

W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:52 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3

It occurs every time i use sudo apt update

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem, and found a solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163567/apt-target-error-after-re-adding-vs-code-repo). I solved it by removing the `vscode.list` file. You can do that by running:

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list
```

**Note:** In the [original answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1163567/apt-target-error-after-re-adding-vs-code-repo), when they talk about removing `deb [arch=amd64] https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable main` they are referring to that line in your `/etc/apt/sources.list` file. I have not tested that solution though.